# Using AWS services as backend to make an instagram(no videos initially) like app

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, backend

I am using AWS s3 to store images and ec2(t2.micro free tier) instance to save images url and user details.i have tested it and its working fine.

I want to rent servers and make the app live in play store now.
Im confused which ec2 instance i should go with ?

And will i need Load balancers and more than one ec2 instance for the initial phase of 2000-3000 users(for a month)?

Do i need to add any other service?

I am not an expert at managing servers because i have just learnt and yet to learn other AWS services.I want the servers to run well until the user number grows more than 3k.
Would be glad to get exact answers.

Answer (score 1):

Just by saying 3000 users you cannot determine the requests. Each user can make from hundreds to thousands to millions of requests per month based on the type of app/user base. For starters you can start with 1 `t2.micro` instance. This will come under free tier and will manage auto-scaling of instances.

Once your app is live, monitor you instance from CloudWatch(basic monitoring is free) and check if your instance is running optimally. This will give you an idea of the number of servers you might need so that you don't over/under provision servers. This will help you in capacity planning.

EDIT: Keep an eye on CPU Credits activity, specially *CPU Credit Usage* metric. If it's value remains low, your instance is not bursting over base line performance.(applicable only for t2 type instances)

Based on your requirements you can use other AWS Services like RDS(Database), DynamoDB(NoSQL), SNS(notification) and SQS(for queues).

Comment: Thanks for a detailed answer.One more question .Should i use Relational database to store user details and image urls or Use a ec2 instance and setup a db there?

Comment: Since you are using t2.micro, better use RDS. RDS takes care of maintenance, security, backups etc. for you.